# How to obtain a Hash fragment of a URL in Sails Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Currently I am working on a Redirect Functionality in sails in that I am getting an URL of the Following format:

`http://localhost:1337/dashboardview/58fdcb172c88812c5126a753#comment-3580520163`

In that I am not able to parse the Hash fragment value(`#comment-3580520163`). I tried with the `req.url()` and `req.path()` but still i am not getting the # fragment.

Is there way in sails to get the Entire URL with the hash fragments or do we have any modules to get the # fragments.

I am a newbie to sails. Please help me to find a solution for it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: A query string like `?comment=3580520163` would be passed to the server while a hash won't. Could you configure your urls using a query string instead? A hash is only really necessary if you are using it to scroll to an anchor on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't send it to the server, it only available on the client.

> The fragment identifier functions differently than the rest of the URI: namely, its processing is exclusively client-side with no
>   participation from the server — of course the server typically helps
>   to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the
>   processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a Web browser)
>   requests a resource from a Web server, the agent sends the URI to the
>   server, but does not send the fragment. Instead, the agent waits for
>   the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the
>   resource according to the document type and fragment value.[2]

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the url after # in Sails as it is currently unsupported by HTTP specifications. If you write an action to redirect from one subdomain to another, for instance, you won't be able to peek at the URL fragment in that action.
However, if you respond with a 302 redirect (i.e. res.redirect()) the user agent on the other end will preserve the URL fragment/hash and tack it on to the end of the new redirected URL.

Or you can just get the fragments on client side and add them as parameters to send to the server side.

Please refer to Sails Documentation : http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-url

to get the fragments on client side you can use : window.location.hash.substr(1);

Comment: Yes, If i use res.redirect(req.url) then i am getting the hash values preserved in the front end. But is there a way to change the host name from localhost:1337 to localhost:1337/#/ with the preserved hash values